# PowerShell: update O365 AD bulk attributes through csv file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

We are trying to bulk update our Azure Active Directory. We have a excel csv list of UserPrincipalNames that we will update the Title, Department, and Office attributes

```
# Get List of Clinical CMs
$PATH = "C:\Users\cs\Documents\IT Stuff\Project\Azure AD Update\AD-Update-ClinicalCMs-Test.csv"
$CMs = Import-csv $PATH

# Pass CMs into Function
ForEach ($UPN in $CMs) {
# Do AD Update Task Here
Set-Msoluser -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Title "Case Manager" -Department "Clinical" -Office "Virtual"
}
```

The CSV:

```
User.1@domain.com
User.2@domain.com
User.3@domain.com
```

The Set-MsolUser command will work on its own, but it is not working as intended in this For loop. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: That's not a csv file, just a textfile with upn's each on a separate line. For that, use `Get-Content`

Comment: Thank you, Get-Content was the solution

Comment: If your issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer? It may help more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jim Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10505040/jim-xu) commented, here my comment as answer.

The input file you show us is not a CSV file, instead, it is a list of UPN values all on a separate line.

To read these values as string array, the easiest thing to is to use `Get-Content`:

```
$PATH = "C:\Users\cs\Documents\IT Stuff\Project\Azure AD Update\AD-Update-ClinicalCMs-Test.csv"
$CMs = Get-Content -Path $PATH
```

Of course, although massive overkill, it *can* be done using the `Import-Csv` cmdlet:

```
$CMs = (Import-Csv -Path $PATH -Header upn).upn
```